# How convert flex Data grid values to CSV format file?

Tags: java, apache-flex, flash, air, phpmyadmin

I am new beginner, is it possible the covert flex data grid to CSV file format with out use any backend (java,php ..) file ? . Because I tried with out use  bankend . is it convert or not ? So any one give suggest me . or which is best method to convert ?